# Build a permanent playlist in podcasts.app iOS 11? Listen Now vs. Library?

Tags: iphone, podcasts.app

My current workflow for podcast episodes: “play later”, adds to queue, and I play through my queue which is ever growing.

This works more or less but it’s not ideal. I want functionality like YouTube where I have a playlist that I can play through and edit easily.

*YouTube let’s me “add to watch later” which puts it in an organized playlist I can edit easily and watch at my leisure. It’s permanent and can’t be overwritten. I can play a new video without tampering with the playlist and I can also change the order of the playlist and delete videos after I’ve watched them.*

I don’t want to use a third party app.

---

UPDATE: I'm experimenting with achieving this either using the "Listen Now" tab or the "Library" by deleting episodes as they come in (opposite approach I'm looking for, would rather add things I would like to listen to instead of remove the ones I don't want to listen to but this is the only solution I could find), I've also unsubscribed from a ton of shows to reduce the noise.

[Articles](https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/10/podcasts-in-ios-11-interface-updates-seasons-podcast/) sort've explain what the tabs do but nobody seems to be concerned with creating some a playlist which kind of perplexes me.

Example: 5 notifications of new podcasts and 1 sounds interesting (and I don't currently have time to listen) so I go in and add that podcast to my queue and get rid of the other notifications. This is how I do it on YouTube too (but there I can even categorize into different playlists too). The issue is that my queue has over 20 podcasts on it...so what if I want to [restore my phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/306484/will-restore-from-icloud-backup-erase-podcast-app-queue-ios)?

---

UPDATE 2: restore kept my podcasts queue! so they are "permanent" unless you overwrite etc.

Comment: How much against are you to using a third party app? Like in a scenario where I'm like "here's an app that can do exactly what you want and the default app can't do it..." You interested or no?

Comment: @Joonas currently podcasts can be deleted from the queue accidentally either by going to the next podcast or playing a new podcast directly without adding it to the queue. If I forgot which podcast it was, there’s no way to get it back. On YouTube you have to intentionally delete a video to remove it from your playlist.

Comment: Right. Same convenience, but a permanent playlist. Got it.