# Will restore from iCloud backup erase podcast.app queue (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, podcasts, podcasts.app

My iPhone is sluggish so I want to restore it.

Concerned I’ll lose my long podcast queue if I restore. Would iCloud/iTunes restore retain my queue?

Comment: What is your exact question?  Is it about the what the restore will do to your podcast queue or is it how to restore your iPhone (iTunes or iCloud) to fix it being sluggish?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just restored my iPhone (from backup) using iTunes and my Podcasts queue WAS restored!

**Restore will NOT remove Podcast Queue**.